# error: patch 2147483647 defined multiple times

Tags: rpmbuild

Sorry for the cryptic title, but that's exactly what I get:

```
bash-4.2# rpmbuild --rebuild dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
Installing dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mock does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mock does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mock does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mock does not exist - using root
error: patch 2147483647 defined multiple times
```

What am I doing wrong with my rpmbuild command ?

For reference:

```
bash-4.2# rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.11.3
```

Full steps:

```
% cat Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:7
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN curl -O https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/dcmtk/3.6.7/3.fc39/src/dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install rpm-build
RUN rpmbuild --rebuild dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
```

---

Sames goes for:

```
% cat Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:7
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN curl -O https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/dcmtk/3.6.7/3.fc39/src/dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install rpm-build cmake gcc-c++ libjpeg-devel \
 libpng-devel libtiff-devel libxml2-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel doxygen \
 git-core
RUN rpm -i dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
WORKDIR  /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
RUN rpmbuild -ba dcmtk.spec
```

results in:

```
% docker build .
[...]
error: patch 2147483647 defined multiple times
The command '/bin/sh -c rpmbuild -ba dcmtk.spec' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

---

Looking at the .spec file here are the patches defined:

```
% grep Patch: dcmtk.spec
Patch:      0001-Use-system-CharLS-include.patch
Patch:      0002-Add-FindCharLS.patch
Patch:      0003-Find-and-include-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0004-Use-cmake-suggested-locations-for-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0005-Correct-CharLS-API-call.patch
Patch:      0006-Remove-reference-to-bundled-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0007-Update-JLS_ERROR-to-jpegls_error-in-CharLS-usage.patch
Patch:      0008-Correct-JpegLsReadHeader-arguments.patch
Patch:      0009-Update-JlsParameters-for-new-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0010-Correct-JpegLsDecode-arguments-for-CharLS-2.patch
Patch:      0011-Update-ilv-for-new-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0012-Correct-extra-include-for-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0013-Update-errors-to-use-enum-class-in-CharLS-2.patch
Patch:      0014-Define-BYTE-for-CharLS.patch
Patch:      0015-Update-colorTransformation-for-CharLS-2.patch
Patch:      0016-Update-JpegLsEncode-for-CharLS-2.patch
Patch:      0017-Increase-sleep-for-tests.patch
Patch:      0018-CVE-2022-43272-Fixed-memory-leak-in-single-process-mode.patch
```

---

I discover that I can comment any of the two applied patch to get pass this error, eg:

> sed -e '/0017-Increase-sleep-for-tests.patch/ s/^#*/#/' -i dcmtk.spec

But I am curious where does this number `2147483647` comes from ?

Comment: It looks like the source rpm hasn't been built correctly. Also I'd recommend using `mock` to build rpm packages.  So first extract the `.spec` file from the source rpm:  `rpm2cpio  dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm |cpio -ivdm '*.spec'`, after that inspect your `spec` file and see if `patch 2147483647`  has been defined multiple times

Comment: Updated with full patch names

Comment: I was able to build the package on my fedora 38 using `rpmbuild --rebuild dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm ` without issues. So not sure what else you are doing

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example is given as `Dockerfile`. Can you try on your side?

Comment: The docker doesn't do anything different. I don't have a docker environment so can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the rpmbuild on amazonlinux/2 does not support 'Patch:' with multiples patches. You have to use the explicit alternate forms:

```
Patch0:        foo.patch
Patch1:        bar.patch
```

It may be fixed in later amazonlinux image.

Ref:

- https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/rpm-patch.html